# Empirical probability distribution is not consistent with the true distribution

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to simulate sampling distribution of sample mean from a normal population with mean 170 and st.deviation 2. According to math, a sample of size 20 will have the sampling mean distribution a normal with mean 170 and st.deviation of 2/(20^0.5).

I am plotting the empirical sampling mean distribution for n=20, with 50000 experiments. Then I use `a.hist(sample_means1, bins = 100)`, take the heights and divide each by 50000 , and then plot again using `ax.plot` to get the empirical sampling mean distribution. But the result does not seem to be consistent. Here is the code:

```
import math
import statistics
import random

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def normal_pdf(m, s, x):
  coeff = 1/(s*math.sqrt(2*math.pi))
  expn = math.exp( -0.5*((x - m)/s)**2 );
  return coeff*expn

n_exp = 50000

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sample_means1 = []
for i in range(n_exp):
  sample = [random.gauss(170, 2) for i in range(20)] 
  smean = statistics.mean(sample)
  sample_means1.append(smean)

f,a = plt.subplots()
h = a.hist(sample_means1, bins = 100)
probs = [i/n_exp for i in h[0]]
xl = min(h[1])
xr = max(h[1])
x = [xl + (xr-xl)*i/1000 for i in range(1001)]

ax.plot(h[1][0: 100], probs, '-', color = "black")
ax.plot(x, [normal_pdf(170, 2/math.sqrt(20), i) for i in x], '-', color = "blue")
fig.savefig("tes.png")
```

Plot result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a probability distribution you should divide the heights by the number of experiments times the width of the bins, i.e.

```
widths = (h[1][1:]-h[1][:-1])
probs = h[0]/(widths*n_exp)
mid_points = (h[1][1:]+h[1][:-1])/2

ax.plot(mid_points, probs, '-', color = "black")
ax.plot(x, [normal_pdf(170, 2/math.sqrt(20), i) for i in x], '-', color = "blue")

fig.savefig("tes.png")
```

[image: comparison of theoretical and empirical distribution]